# Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference - End, explode and implode

Tags: php

I am getting the follow PHP notice as a result of testing migration to PHP 7.4:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference

On line:

```
$row->type = end(explode(",",(implode(array_slice(explode ( ':',  $row->global_id), -2, 1)))));
```

This is in:

```
  $roots = array();
    foreach ($data as $row) {   
        $row->type = end(explode(",",(implode(array_slice(explode ( ':',  $row->global_id), -2, 1)))));
        if ($row->parent_global_id === null) {
            $roots[]= $row;
        } else {
            $data[$row->parent_global_id]->children[] = $row;
        }
        unset($row->parent_global_id);
        unset($row->global_id);
    }
```

How should that line be written for PHP 7?

Comment: Is this `explode ( ':'` correct? Should that space be there after explode?

Comment: yes, it works, just want to remove the notice

Comment: `end()` needs an array in a variable, because it will change it. It [says so in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end).

Comment: using end with explode in the same line will throw such warning. Move the ``end()`` to the next line. Or use ``@`` before the ``@end(explode(.....)`` to suppress the warning

Comment: @OMiShah: That is truly bad advice. You might be supressing this notice, but you might also suppress other problems you need to know about.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, yes you're right, and I don't really RECOMMEND but if he wish so.

Comment: As much for readability as anything it makes sense to break down that complex statement into it's constituent parts. Perhaps it will be 5 lines rather than one but easier to follow for others later if they need to debug.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I wholeheartedly agree with that. It can probably be simplified a lot as well.

Answer (score 1):

`end` moves the internal pointer of an array.

So you have do `$result = explode(); $row->type = end($result);`

Then the notice will be no more showing up.

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.end.php

Related functions: `reset(), next(), prev()`

Comment: do not answer duplicate question !!

Comment: Downvote for answering duplicate question and NOT for the correct answer. I have removed my DV. But don't answer next dup ques time, please. :) :)

Comment: @OMiShah I just want to be helpfull and don't now all the rules here. :-)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I already marked this question as dup FYI. If I had sufficient right then I would have done that already :)

Comment: @OMiShah Ah, yes, I see it now, after I refreshed the page.